# XSL for each for different nodes in XML file

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet  type="text/xsl" href="coursestyle.xsl"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <ns0:FindCoursesForOffenderResponse xmlns:ns0="http://H.FindCoursesForOffenderResponse">
         <ns0:SiteList>
            <ns0:SiteEntity>
               <ns0:SiteId>10</ns0:SiteId>
               <ns0:SiteName>Ramada Watford</ns0:SiteName>
            </ns0:SiteEntity>
            <ns0:SiteEntity>
               <ns0:SiteId>20</ns0:SiteId>
               <ns0:SiteName>Ramada Jarvis (Comet) Hotel</ns0:SiteName>
            </ns0:SiteEntity>
         </ns0:SiteList>
         <ns0:CourseList>
            <ns0:CourseEntity>
               <ns0:CourseId>50</ns0:CourseId>
               <ns0:SiteId>10</ns0:SiteId>
            </ns0:CourseEntity>
            <ns0:CourseEntity>
               <ns0:CourseId>10</ns0:CourseId>
               <ns0:SiteId>10</ns0:SiteId>
            </ns0:CourseEntity>
            <ns0:CourseEntity>
               <ns0:CourseId>20</ns0:CourseId>
               <ns0:SiteId>20</ns0:SiteId>
            </ns0:CourseEntity>
         </ns0:CourseList>
      </ns0:FindCoursesForOffenderResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I want to select the `SiteName` for each `CourseEntity`. For example for the `CourseID = 50` the `SiteName` should be `Ramada Watford`.

So far I have this XSL but it doesn't work.

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns0="http://H.FindCoursesForOffenderResponse" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<xsl:output method="html"/>
<xsl:param  name="lnum">123</xsl:param>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <ul>

    <xsl:for-each select="s:Envelope/s:Body/ns0:FindCoursesForOffenderResponse/ns0:CourseList/ns0:CourseEntity">
        <xsl:variable  name="currEntity"><xsl:value-of select="ns0:SiteId"/></xsl:variable>
            <xsl:value-of select="$currEntity"/><br/>
            <xsl:for-each select="s:Envelope/s:Body/ns0:FindCoursesForOffenderResponse/ns0:SiteList/ns0:SiteEntity[ns0:SiteId=$currEntity]">            
          <li>
            <xsl:value-of select="ns0:SiteName"/>

          </li>
              </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:for-each>

    </ul>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The first `for-each` loop runs through `CourseEntities` and the inner loop is trying to find the relevant site name for each course id.

Any idea?

output

```
<couseID> - <sitename>
50 - Ramada Watford
20 -   Ramada Jarvis (Comet) Hotel
```

Comment: What output do you want? Please edit the question to show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For-each loops are normally best avoided in XSLT. Try this templated approach.

Runnable demo at [this XMLPlayground](http://www.xmlplayground.com/0GKHFB)

```
<!-- kick things off -->
<xsl:template match="s:Envelope/s:Body/ns0:FindCoursesForOffenderResponse">
    <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates select='ns0:CourseList/ns0:CourseEntity' />
    </ul>
</xsl:template>

<!-- site entities... -->
<xsl:template match='ns0:CourseEntity'>
    <li>
        <xsl:value-of select='ns0:CourseId' />
        -
        <!-- ...find corresponding site name -->
        <xsl:value-of select='../../ns0:SiteList/ns0:SiteEntity[ns0:SiteId = current()/ns0:SiteId]/ns0:SiteName' />
    </li>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer Utkanos. It worked. I have no idea how it works though. :(

Comment: A lot of people fall into for-each when they start XSL because it's what they've come from in other languages. XSLT works differently and requires a different way of thinking. Essentially what I'm doing there is applying templates (the crucial concept of XSLT) to certain nodes - that is, running them through a particular transformation. I then look up the tree and back inside to find corresponding site names. XSLT can take a while to get your head round, but it's easy eventually :)